# .htaccess ErrorDocument 404 won't redirect, Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: .htaccess

In  var/ww/myht I have 2 files: `error404.html` and a `.htaccess` file that contains:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
```

It just doesn't redirect.

p.s. mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: It is not supposed to **redirect**. `ErrorDocument` is here to tell Apache which document to display when requested resource is not found (404 error code). I see no rewrite rules **at all** in your question .. therefore I see nothing to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

This probably belongs on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) as it's not programming-related.

Still, remember that .htaccess files are NOT used by default, so unless you properly configured the AllowOverride directive for the directory in question (/var/www/myht) it will not be picked up.

This configuration needs to be done in Apache's config files.

Start reading here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Good luck!